# Find the maximum value in a drop-down list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down list with numerical values:

```
<select name="a">
   <option value="1">asdsadas</option>
   <option value="1">wqecsdc</option>
   <option value="10">nmnmbn</option>
   <option value="16">assadsa</option>
   <option value="12">uuyuyuy</option>
   <option value="60">xzXz</option>
   <option value="55">vbbnbnm</option>
   <option value="13">eerrt</option>
</select>
```

I need to find the highest numerical value within this list. (In this case, it's 60.)

I was thinking of looping using `.each`, but is there a shorter way?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that Underscore.js is good for. I think with Underscore it'd be something like `_($('#theSelect option').get()).chain().pluck('value').max().value()`

Comment: @pointy could you explain what that is doing, and why did you not post that as an answer ?

Comment: Check out Underscore (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) - it's a library that provides some functional programming utilities. I didn't post an answer because I don't think "use this other library" is really directly helpful. That code sample preps an Underscore wrapper, then plucks out the "value" attribute from the elements into an array, and then finds the maximum one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function findMaxValue(element) {
    var maxValue = undefined;
    $('option', element).each(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        val = parseInt(val, 10);
        if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < val) {
            maxValue = val;
        }
    });
    return maxValue;
}

alert(findMaxValue($('select[name=a]')));
```

Answer (score 18):

This works fine for me, pretty straight forward:

```
$('select option:last').val()
```

edit: misunderstood the question but might become handy for others, in most cases you have the options in the select element ordered desc or asc.

Answer (score 0):

## This would work..!!

```
var temp=0;

var currentValue, maxValue;

$('select option').each(function(){

currentValue = $(this).val();

maxValue = Math.max(temp, currentValue);

temp=currentValue;

});

console.log(maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="aktivite_type" id="aktivite_type">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="6">B</option>
  <option value="10">C</option>
  <option value="11">D</option>
  <option value="8">E</option>
  <option value="9">F</option>
  <option value="7">F</option>
</select>

<button onclick="JSF__selectLastTypeValue()">Select Value</button>

<script>

function JSF__selectLastTypeValue()
    {
    var temp=0;
    var currentValue, maxValue;
    $('#aktivite_type option').each(function(i,v)
        {
        currentValue = v.value;
        maxValue = Math.max(temp, currentValue);
        temp=maxValue;
        });
    $("#aktivite_type").val(maxValue);
    }
    
   </script>
```

Comment: Please don't just post code! Add an explanation as well for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score -1):

```
var maxValue = undefined;
$('option', element).each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = parseInt(val, 10);
  if(!isNaN(val)) {
    if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < val) {
      maxValue = val;
    }
  }
});
return maxValue;
```